# Move files based on arithmetic conditions on filename

Tags: ubuntu, command-line

I have a folder with a bunch of files following this structure:
`image_<N1>_<N2>.png`
where N1 ranges 0:238002, N2 ranges 0:3.

I want to move to another folder only the files that have N1 <= 18003 and N2 == 0.
Is there a quick and easy way to do it?

N1 isn't formatted to have a fixed amount of digits. E.g. N1=23 will be `image_23_0.png`, *not* `image_000023_0.png`.

The OS is Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

With `bash` you could do:

```
mv image_{0..18003}_0.png target_dir/
```

As `N2` is always `0`, one can use it as fixed string.
`{a..b}` evaluates to all option in the range from `a` to `b`. This would also work for the alphabet, but be careful with locales using other than the 26-letter alphabet.

---

For avoiding an error due to too long argument lists, use `xargs`

```
seq 0 18003 | xargs -I{} mv image_'{}'_0.png target_dir/
```

`xargs` is a tool to translate a list of input into a series of commands with focus of running the command as few times as possible. Simply spoken.

Here `seq` creates a sequence of the numbers 0 to 18003, which is piped (`|` = forwarded) as input for `xargs`. `-I{}` means to replace `{}` in the specified command with the incomming input for creating the series of commands.

Comment: In general this approach is prone to `argument list too long` error, but the OP probably won't hit the limit. Not entirely perfect solution, yet "quick and easy" as requested. +1.

Comment: oh nice that was much easier than I thought, I'll let you know if I hit any limit once it finishes, thank you!

Comment: If it's already running you haven't (and won't) hit a limit, @SpaceLover

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski agreed. added `xargs` alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to do everything in a slightly longer bash script, taking advantage of bash's pattern matching and pattern extracting operators. Something like this:

```
# Be sure to set this properly - this will
# fail as written
target=<...some other directory>
# adjust these as needed
N1limit=18003
N2value=0

# read from the output of the ls command,
# one line at a time, respecting spaces, etc.
# Using read's default variable (REPLY)
# saves some quoting and mangling headaches.
while IFS=\  read -r; do
    fileName="${REPLY}"

    # CONSIDER ADDING LOGIC HERE TO CHECK IF fileName
    #   a) refers to a file, not a directory, and
    #   b) matches the desired pattern;
    # IF IT DOESN'T, continue to the next file

    # get everything up to the end of N1
    N1End="${fileName%_*}"
    # get N1 itself
    N1="${N1End#*_}"
    # get everything up to the beginning of N2
    N2Start="${fileName##*_}"
    # get N2 itself
    N2="${N2Start%.*}"
    # do the move IFF N1 is at or below the limit
    # AND N2 is equal to the desired value
    if [[ $n1 -le $N1limit && $N2 -eq $N2value ]]; then
        mv "${fileName}" "${target}"
    fi
done <<<$(ls)
```

Comment: Even if your script solves the problem (I don't know, I haven't tested), I won't vote up. My reasons: (1) For me this does not look like "a quick and easy way". The question uses this exact phrase and I read it as an explicit requirement. OK, neither "quick" nor "easy" is strictly defined, so you may as well consider your script "quick and easy". If you *really* do then kudos (well, sort of), still not an upvote. (2) [Parsing the output of `ls` is wrong](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski hey, that's fine. Someone else may see this and find it useful, and that's the real point. I tend to prefer one liners wherever possible, but have learned whenever I have a large number of files to manipulate, or any more complex task, it's worthwhile to write a script to separate out bits of logic and allow for better exception handling.